# How to use UIWebview as RichTextLable?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I came to know that UIWebView can be used as a Richtextlable ,but don't know how to implement it.Can any one help me out!

Answer (score 0):

Check this out [might help you](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/tag/uiwebview)

You will need to includejava-script code which can actually create a richTextBox

Answer (score 0):

You have to use html tags to render the data on webview. You have to create String with html tags and later you have to display on webview.

```
    [webView loadHTMLString:newString baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: I need to enter text through key board,can i use UITextview for that?

Comment: I think you enter the data from UITextview. For that text you need to show different colors like rich text

Comment: not exatly,i neet change font styles bold to italic and vice versa

Comment: Do you have idea about HTML tags? Using that tags you can customize your text and can display in Webview.